# Entity class must have non argumented constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I am studying JPA, so while studying on a [JPA BLOG Vogella 1.2 Entity Heading](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html), i came across a line which says:

> All entity classes must define a primary key, must have a non-arg
>   constructor and or not allowed to be final

I am not able to understand this line. Do we need to specifically write a non-argumented constructor, because a default non argumented constructor is always inherited by classes.

what do they mean by not allowing to be final, do this mean we can always extend an Entity class? If so why is this compulsion, why it can not be final

Comment: A default constructor in an entity is needed, when constructors are overloaded. Entity classes may be proxied. Any class which is proxiable cannot be final such as EJBs and CDI beans. You will receive a compile-time error (something along the line - `Class is unproxyable`), if you attempt to make them final.

Comment: I can understand that JPA uses some concept like Class proxies and it needs class to be non-final. Is it similar to what is mentioned as lazy data loading. I think i need to study both of these concepts , i have not heard of.

Comment: FWIW Not all implementations use "class proxies", and so not all have this "final" limitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, you get non arg constructor when there is no constructor defined in your class which has nothing to do with JPA. Yes if you are defining a constructor, then you have to define no arg constructor like:

```
 public class Student {
      public Student() {}//default ctor which is needed by JPA to convert row from DB to java object
      public Student(int id) {..}//ctor which accepts one arg
 }
```

Making class final meaning you can't subclass. JPA vendor's like Hibernate creates proxy to lazily fetch rows which will ultimately limit your options for performance tuning. Hence you see that your class may/may not be final depending on your use case.

Comment: Plz correct me if i am wrong.

so i dont have a choice to make it final in case i am using Hibernate implementation. But in case of other implementations, i may have a choice.

Comment: So if you want data to be loaded lazily, then dont mark your class as final else by using any framework, you could mark your class as final.

Comment: What do you mean by loading data lazily? I thought data is committed on commit() only

Comment: I think i would have to study loading data lazily further, if you can give me link to a good tutorial, that would be much helpful.As far as this question is concerned, i am accepting your answer.